# Logic level converter for SPI

Tags: spi

I'm using an SPI interface in Raspberry Pi for programming platforms. I have a need to use various logic levels (1.8V, 3.3V, 5V). Is there any IC which allows for dynamic switching between logic levels? I would prefer to avoid using a combination of jumpers and transistors.

Comment: as you've guessed, these ICs are called "Logic level converter" or "level shifters". Since this boils down to you going to mouser.com, clicking through to the logic devices, and then finding a level shifter that fits your need, we'll let you do that – product recommendation questions are generally offtopic

Comment: You are saying that you want to switch logic levels which suggest you have multiple devices connect to you SPI. How are you planning that when you set the converter to 5V the shared SPI, CLK and MOSI 5V signals do not blow-up the 1V8 chips?

Comment: Does the Rasp Pi use 5V levels for SCK, MOSI, and slave select?

Comment: Nope, it is a 3V3 chip.

Answer (score 1):

Pick the highest-voltage buss as your common point.  Then simply use a logic-level converter between that buss and each individual voltage level.

There may be additional effort required if you have multiple devices talking to the RPi.  Specifically, you need to enable only driver talking to the RPi's receive pin.  This is not difficult but you need to be aware of the problem.  In general, use the enable line for each SPI device to also control the TX output enable of the level converter.  TX, in this case, refers to the pin that is feeding the RX pin on the RPi.